# How can I bulk add existing commerce products to a display node?

Tags: commerce

pretty simple, i want the ability to add more than one existing product at a time to a node. i am already using bulk product creation to help me create all the variations of the product quickly. but then after that, i have to add them 1 by 1 to the display node. i would love the ability to just add a product range by product ID or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

entity reference view widget module solved my problem. it basically allows you to replace the add existing product button with a view. just customize the view to select any range of existing products you want and add them to the display node. saved my a boatload of time.

Answer (score 1):

You say you're using "bulk product creation", does that mean you're the using the [Feeds module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds)? You can use it along with [Commerce Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_feeds) in two steps. First create all products, and then create all product displays linked to those products. You can, for example, use the `title` field as an identifier to link the two.

There's a handy tutorial on Vimeo by [Randy Fey](https://www.drupal.org/u/rfay) called [Importing Products with Commerce Feeds](https://vimeo.com/22731881).

Comment: i was referring to the module commerce bulk product creation. it allows you to create ALL variations of a product in one click. so like for the tshirt example, if you have small, medium, and large sizes as an option and colors red, white, and blue as an option the module will spit out products for all variations (small red, small white, small blue, medium red etc ...)

this still doesn't do the last step of associating the products with a node. using entity reference view widget module i can change the widget type of the product reference field to a view and then select any and all products